# How to allow access between network segments in Keenetic?

Tags: networking, firewall, router

I have Keenetic Sprinter with default firmware (latest) in which I have configured 2 segments:

- Home Segment `192.168.1.0`, `255.255.255.0/24`, `DHCP enabled`
- IoT Segment `192.168.2.0`, `255.255.255.0/24`, `DHCP enabled`

I need to allow connectivity between these segments, but after setting up the respective firewall rules, I still get `Destination host unreachable` when trying to ping.
If that matters, all of the devices on both subnets are assigned static IPs. Also, all of the devices on both networks are connected over Wi-Fi.

The firewall rules that I have set up are:

- For `Home Segment` permit `IP/TCP/UDP` from `192.168.1.0` mask `255.255.255.0/24` to `192.168.2.0` mask `255.255.255.0/24`
- For `IoT Segment` permit `IP/TCP/UDP` from `192.168.2.0` mask `255.255.255.0/24` to `192.168.1.0` mask `255.255.255.0/24`

Is there something else needs done to achieve interconnectivity?

Comment: Welcome to serverfault, where you can only ask business-related questions that affect business envoiroment. Due to this nature, I assume you did not read [ask]. Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.